# Error 999999 in Zonal Statistics estimation using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics, error-999999

I have multiple rasters saved in "Zonal.gdb". All the rasters in "Zonal.gdb" and "TownWilson_PrjUTM" have projected coordinates "WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_15N". I want to clip each raster to the extent in the shapefile (TownWilson_PrjUTM) and resample to 10 meter resolution and estimate zonal statistics as shown in the code below.

I am getting an error as shown below. Cannot understand why I am getting the error even though I have projected rasters and shapefile to the same projected coordinates.

Can somebody help me to figure this out?

```
import arcpy, os, arcinfo
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *


arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
env.workspace = "H:/Arkansas_Flood/Zonal.gdb"
watershedFeat = "H:/Arkansas_Flood/Zonal.gdb/TownWilson_PrjUTM"
outDir = "H:/Table/"

for raster in arcpy.ListRasters(): 
    raster_name = os.path.basename(raster).rstrip(os.path.splitext(raster)[1])
    ## Clip Raster Dataset by known extent - Left Bottom Right Top
    clip_raster = arcpy.Clip_management(raster, "231366.658400 4140371.653300 280675.622100 4180783.072200", "#", "#", "#", "NONE") # with TownWilson_Prj
    # Process: Project Raster
    finalras = arcpy.Resample_management(clip_raster, "#", "10", "BILINEAR")
    outTable = outDir + raster_name + "_TBL.dbf"
    arcpy.gp.ZonalStatisticsAsTable(watershedFeat,"T_R", finalras, outTable,"NODATA","MEAN") # DATA for precipitation, NODATA for RZSM


arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")
```

---

```
> Error:
> 
> Executing: zonalMeanRev Start Time: Thu Jan 04 23:50:02 2018 Running
> script zonalMeanRev... Failed script zonalMeanRev...
> 
>     Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\jayaskeradl\Desktop\Arkansas_
> Flood\My_Phyton_Scripts\zonal_mean_rev.py", line 46, in <module>
>     clip_raster = arcpy.Clip_management(raster, "231366.658400 4140371.653300 280675.622100 4180783.072200", "#", "#", "#", "NONE") # with TownWilson_Prj   File "c:\program files
> (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 13771, in
> Clip
>     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Clip). Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000628: Cannot set input into
> parameter in_raster.
> 
> 
> Failed to execute (zonalMeanRev).
> 
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\jayaskeradl\Desktop\Arkansas_
> Flood\My_Phyton_Scripts\zonal_mean_rev.py", line 46, in <module>
>     clip_raster = arcpy.Clip_management(raster, "231366.658400 4140371.653300 280675.622100 4180783.072200", "#", "#", "#", "NONE") # with TownWilson_Prj   File "c:\program files
> (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 13771, in
> Clip
>     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. The table already exists. No spatial reference exists. Failed to execute
> (Clip).
> 
> 
> Failed to execute (zonalMeanRev).


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jayaskeradl\Desktop\Arkansas_ Flood\My_Phyton_Scripts\zonal_mean_rev.py", line 53, in <module>
    finalras = arcpy.Resample_management("H:/Arkansas_Flood/Zonal.gdb/newRaster", "#", "10", "BILINEAR")
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 14243, in Resample
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
The table already exists.
No spatial reference exists.
The table was not found. [VAT_newRaster]
Failed to execute (Resample).


Failed to execute (zonalMeanRev).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the out_raster parameter:

[image]

Try something like:

```
clip_raster = arcpy.Clip_management(raster, "231366.658400 4140371.653300 280675.622100 4180783.072200", "H:/Arkansas_Flood/Zonal.gdb/newRaster", "#", "#", "NONE")
```